# FusedLocationClient returning null values for some few users

Tags: android, location

In my Android app, I'm currently using the Fused Location Provider api (see code below) to get my users' locations and I have some rare complaints about my app not being able to get their own location in the app.

```
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if(locationResult.getLastLocation() != null)
                    currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            }
        };
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,null);
        locationOn = true;
    }
```

After some inspection, it seems that it would sometimes keep returning null values for a certain period of time (or forever) and my app wouldn't work. Other GPS apps work just as fine (Google Maps, for instance).

Is my implementation correct or is this something external like Google Play Services being put on battery saving mode?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct, but location provider sometimes returns null. You may have to handle it properly. If you want to manually get location use `LocationManager`.

Try this snippet form my code (with this I never get null value where I want location as it will at least return last location or properly shows user the error message and how to solve it.:

```
private void updateLocations(){

 String str_latitude = "";

 String str_longitude = "";

 String provider = "";

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    }

    if (!provider.equals("")) {

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

        locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                   Location mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                    if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {

                        str_longitude = String.valueOf(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude());

                        str_latitude = String.valueOf(mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: "+str_latitude + ", Long " + str_longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    if (str_latitude.equals("") || str_longitude.equals("")) {

                        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Couldn't find location, please try again in a moment", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    } else if (provider.equals("")) {

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Seems like all providers of device are disabled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

        snackbar.setAction("Enable", new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Takes user to gps enable settings.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        snackbar.show();
    }

}});
```

Comment: I'm testing your snippet and so far it works great. It's hard to know if its consistent enough, because I have over 2k users for like 2 months and received just 1 complaint so far. I'm still missing an indepth explanation as why problems like the one I described happen

Comment: @arvere I myself have used this code at work in 2 projects, because I was getting null location and app crashes. After searching for so long on the internet I merged multiple solutions into one to make robust location service. Hope it will work as you want, if you find any problems let me know and if you decide to use the code or if you think code can be useful for others, please mark answer as solution.